# How To enhance The Callback handler CXF Interceptor method

Tags: java, spring, authentication, cxf, interceptor

I made a **WSS4JInInterceptor** in a spring bean configuration file as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
        xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
                            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs 
                            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">

        <jaxws:endpoint id="book"
            implementor="net.ma.soap.ws.endpoints.IBookEndPointImpl" address="/bookAuth">
            <jaxws:inInterceptors>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor"></bean>
                <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <map>
                            <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                            <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                            <entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="net.ma.soap.ws.service.ServerPasswordCallback"></entry>
                        </map>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </jaxws:inInterceptors>
        </jaxws:endpoint>
    </beans>
```

The **ServerPasswordCallBack.java** looks like the following

```
    package net.ma.soap.ws.service;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
    import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
    import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;
    import org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSPasswordCallback;

    public class ServerPasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {

        private static final String BUNDLE_LOCATION = "zuth";
        private static final String PASSWORD_PROPERTY_NAME = "auth.manager.password";
        private static String password;

        static {
            final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_LOCATION);
            password = bundle.getString(PASSWORD_PROPERTY_NAME);
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
            WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];
            pc.setPassword(password);
        }
    }
```

With the password verification, everything work just fine.

I'd like to know if there's any other way to enhance the **handle(Callback)** method to make it more sophisticated so it would be able to check more than just one parameter, for example if i can make it check an access token, it would be much more better.

the password property is defined in zuth_fr_FR.properties file as follows

**auth.manager.password=najah**

Comment: WSPasswordCallback has a method getIdentifier() which gets you the value of the username from the security header.

Comment: Is this the only option to make a more sophisticated authentication ?

Comment: As far as I know yes. But with using the password as digest and other features of WS-Security like signature and encryption (Best done with WS-Policy or CryptoCoverageChecker to avoid signature wrapping attacks) it should be sufficient. By the way: storing a passwort as plaintext in a propertiesfile may not the safest way to avoid unauthorized access. ;-)

Comment: @Frank, What do you suggest as strategy of password storage?         and what do you have anything that shows how to implement  the features of WS-Security like **signature** and **encryption**  **WS-Policy** ?

Comment: Regarding the password I recommend to read the [spec](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/13392/wss-v1.1-spec-pr-UsernameTokenProfile-01.htm#_Toc104276210). A simple example of implementing encryption with cxf can be found on their site [http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html)

Comment: Thank you @Frank so much. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do some custom validation on your username and token (such as verify against a directoryservice using LDAP or something similar) you can write your own custom UsernameTokenValidator overriding `verifyPlaintextPassword(UsernameToken usernameToken)` of UsernameTokenValidator and hook it up to your WSS4JInInterceptor adding the following to your bean definition

```
<property name="wssConfig">
        <ref bean="usernameTokenWssConfig"/>
</property>
```

And add the referenced class to your codebase:

```
@Component("usernameTokenWssConfig")
public class usernameTokenWssConfigWSSConfig {
    public usernameTokenWssConfig() {
        setValidator(WSSecurityEngine.USERNAME_TOKEN, new CustomUsernameTokenValidator());
        setRequiredPasswordType(WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT);
    }
}
```